# how to converting a value to hr:mn:sc format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the value of `album.songs[i].duration` in the following code so it displays hr:mn:sc instead of the format it is stored in, which is seconds.  Can I do this in this line of code?

`var $newRow = createSongRow(i + 1, album.songs[i].title, album.songs[i].duration);`

Comment: You want to convert seconds to hr:mn:sc ?

Comment: Show us what you tried, please

Comment: yes, I want to convert seconds to hr:mn:sc

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: this seems like *basic* math....

Answer (score 0):

This is basic math...

```js
function convert(s) {
  var hr = (Math.floor(s / 3600));
  var mn = (Math.floor(s % 3600 / 60));
  var sc = (Math.floor(s % 60));
  
  return hr +":"+ mn +":"+ sc;
}


/* for example */
var seconds = 345432;
console.log(convert(seconds));
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up not needing the hrs so i used the following:`const filterTimeCode = (timeInSeconds) => { let seconds = parseFloat(timeInSeconds); let mn = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60); let sc = Math.floor(seconds % 60); return(mn +":"+ sc); };`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to convert a duration (in seconds) in the format of hr:mn:sc, we can follow the below approach in vanilla javascript:

```
var duration = 5000; // seconds
var hour = parseInt(duration / 3600); // as 1 hour = 3600 seconds
var minutes = parseInt((duration - (hour * 3600)) / 60); // as 1 minute = 60 seconds
var seconds = duration - (hour * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
var durationStr = hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
console.log(durationStr); // should print 1:23:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Hearner's answer, with padding for minutes and seconds < 10:

```js
function pad(num) {
  if (num < 10) return '0' + num;
  return num;
}


function convert(s) {
  var hr = (Math.floor(s / 3600));
  var mn = pad(Math.floor(s % 3600 / 60));
  var sc = pad(Math.floor(s % 60));
  
  return hr +":"+ mn +":"+ sc;
}


/* for example */
var seconds = 3661;
console.log(convert(seconds)); // 1:01:01 instead of 1:1:1

// and you would use:
// var $newRow = createSongRow(i + 1, album.songs[i].title, convert(album.songs[i].duration));
```

Comment: Thanks Kev!  I am a coding newbie.  I ended up not needing the hours since all inputs will be less than 1 hr. Here is what I used:              
 `const filterTimeCode = (timeInSeconds) => {
    let seconds = parseFloat(timeInSeconds);
    let mn = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60);
    let sc = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    return(mn +":"+ sc);
};`

Comment: @compostbrain the seconds will still need a padding function though, otherwise, for example, 61 seconds looks like "1:1" instead of "1:01".  BTW as far as this site goes: any answers you found helpful, feel free to upvote, and accept one where appropriate.